# Why can I not load files using "c++ [insert file name here].cpp"

Tags: c++, shell, cmd, command-line

I have not used C++ in for about one year. But it seems that I fail when attempting to run a simple program again. The way I remember it:

1. change directory `cd` to the desired file location.
2. Type `c++ [insert file name here].cpp`
3. Type `a./.exe` to actually run the program.

However, when attempting to run the program, I get an error message at step 2, stating :

> 'c++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

What has changed? I've also seen some suggestions of `cl` on the internet but when using it, I get the exact same message.

I believe the software I have is associated with NetBeans. Any ideas to alleviate this problem?

Comment: You do not have a C++ compiler. Whether or not you had it before, or why it's no longer on your system, this is something that only you can figure out, obviously. Maybe your PATH is wrong. Can be anything, unfortunately only you have access to your computer, and can investigate what is or isn't installed on it. NetBeans is not a C++ compiler.

Comment: Try g++ instead of c++ to compile your program

Comment: Ah, I installed Python a few months ago. Could that be it? How would I fix it

Comment: Why would you think installing Python would mess with your C++ build environment??

Comment: Set your environment variable

Comment: Which os are you using?